# How do I set the project programmatically for the python SDK?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api-python-client

I do not want to set the project with the gcloud cli or environment variables, I want to do this programmatically. I'm attempthing to use client_options, but this is not working:

```
from google.cloud import translate_v2 as translate

def translate_text(target: str, text: str):
    translate_client = translate.Client(
         client_options={
             "quota_project_id": "my-proj-id",
         }
    )
    ...
```

I get an error: `Cloud Translation API has not been used in project <A DIFFERENT PROJECT>`.

How do I set it to a specific project in the constructor?

## Edit

I found another code example for the same API (annoyingly I have know idea what the difference is and which one I should be using).

But this also is not working, it does when I globally set: `gcloud auth application-default set-quota-project my-project`, but I don't want to do that. I'll have no way of running gcloud where this containerized app will be running.

```
# Imports the Google Cloud Translation library
from google.cloud import translate


# Initialize Translation client
def translate_text(
    text: str = "YOUR_TEXT_TO_TRANSLATE", project_id: str = "YOUR_PROJECT_ID"
) -> translate.TranslationServiceClient:
    """Translating Text."""

    client = translate.TranslationServiceClient(
        client_options={
            "quota_project_id": "my-proj",
        }
    )

    location = "global"

    parent = f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}"

    # Translate text from English to French
    # Detail on supported types can be found here:
    # https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/supported-formats
    request = {
        "parent": parent,
        "contents": [text],
        "mime_type": "text/plain",  # mime types: text/plain, text/html
        "source_language_code": "en-US",
        "target_language_code": "fr",
    }

    response = client.translate_text(**request)

    # Display the translation for each input text provided
    for translation in response.translations:
        print(f"Translated text: {translation.translated_text}")

    return response


translate_text("hello", "my-proj")
```

I get: `google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Cloud Translation API has not been used in project <MY SERVICE ACCOUNTS PROJECT> before or it is disabled.`

This GSA is in a different project than the project with the API enabled and I cannot change that. I now this works with gcloud cli, how do I do this in code?

Comment: You can set this environment variable in your runtime execution: GOOGLE_CLOUD_QUOTA_PROJECT

Comment: Nope. Running `export GOOGLE_CLOUD_QUOTA_PROJECT=myproj` in the same session where I'm running my script does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Did you try to use translate v3 library?

Comment: My snippet is directly from their own quickstart docs: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/translate-text-advance. Is there own documentation using the wrong library? I already found a bug in it so maybe its totally untrustworthy?

Comment: Libraries and API move fast, and there is simple human being documentation. So, yes, desync and bugs can happen!

Answer (score 0):

This was the only way I could get this to work. I swear other clients made it easy to set the project, so I'm guessing maybe it's just this API or maybe I'm using an old library version or something.

Maybe I should be using the discovery API and building the client through that? I could not find an example though.

Also, so many terrible errors that made this take way longer to figure out than it should have. If the service account doesn't have perms to the project at all I got this error which is so wrong it's ridiculous:

> google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Invalid 'parent'.;
> Invalid resource name project id. Identifier must contain only
> lowercase letters, digits, periods, a colon, or hyphens.;  Resource
> type: location

Code:

```
# Imports the Google Cloud Translation library
from google.cloud import translate
import google.auth


# Initialize Translation client
def translate_text(
    text: str = "YOUR_TEXT_TO_TRANSLATE", project_id: str = "YOUR_PROJECT_ID"
) -> translate.TranslationServiceClient:
    """Translating Text."""
    
    # Manually build creds with quota_project_id set
    credentials, _ = google.auth.default(quota_project_id=project_id)

    client = translate.TranslationServiceClient(
        credentials=credentials,
        # This is actually not required if creds are pass in it seems
        client_options={
            "quota_project_id": project_id,
        },
    )

    location = "global"
    parent = f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}"

    # Translate text from English to French
    # Detail on supported types can be found here:
    # https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/supported-formats
    request = {
        "parent": parent,
        "contents": [text],
        "mime_type": "text/plain",  # mime types: text/plain, text/html
        "source_language_code": "en-US",
        "target_language_code": "fr",
    }

    response = client.translate_text(**request)

    # Display the translation for each input text provided
    for translation in response.translations:
        print(f"Translated text: {translation.translated_text}")

    return response


translate_text("hello", "my-project")
```